# How to enable code coverage for web service code written in java and angular

Tags: java, angular, code-coverage

Any hint will be appreciated.

**P1:** I have microservice with spring boot project, code with java and angular.
**P1.testing:** Selenium code for UI testing with java.

**For reference:** My project name is P1 and testing project is P1.testing.

Now i want to enable code coverage for P1. Which tool i can use to do same?

How i can include code of P1 in my testing project to enable code coverage?

Answer (score 0):

Try jacoco test coverage plugin, its being used widely in the projects

Reference:
https://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/maven.html
https://www.baeldung.com/jacoco